# White space in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, react-props

I'm totally new to react native and have been trying to align each image after the text, but I am getting this weird white space, which I don't know how to get rid of. This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

This is my js code:

```
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={[styles.container]}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Mt. Fuji</Text>
            <Image source={require("./images/pic.jpeg")} style={styles.uriImg} />
            <TextImg
              text="Rick & Morty"
              imageUri={
                "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZjRjOTFkOTktZWUzMi00YzMyLThkMmYtMjEwNmQyNzliYTNmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzQ1ODk3MTQ@._V1_.jpg"
              }
              style={[styles.text, styles.propImg]}
            />
            <TextImg
              text="The Butterfly Nebula"
              imageUri={
                "https://www.dualdove.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/supernova-dying-star-in-the-shape-of-a-butterfly.jpg"
              }
              style={[styles.text, styles.propImg]}
            />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      );
    }
```

is a custom component in another file called comp.

This is my CSS:

```
    Const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      uriImg: {
        width: 350, 
        height: 200,
        top:110,
        marginBottom:120
      }, 
      propImg: {
        width: 350, 
        height: 200,
        marginBottom:30
      }, 
      container:{
        backgroundColor: '#a1c5ff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flex:1,
      },
      title: {
        top:100,
        backgroundColor: '#61dafb',
        color: '#20232a',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 50,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
      text:{
        color: '#ffffff',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 30,
        fontFamily: 'Cochin',
      }
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which white space are you referring to?

Comment: Oh, i mean the extra space between the images and the title of those images, blue-colored space. The custom props inside the custom TextImg component.

Comment: show the TextImg component

Comment: `export default function TextImg(props) {
    return (
       <React.Fragment>
          <Text style = {props.style}>{props.text} </Text>
          <Image source={{uri: props.imageUri}}  style={props.style}/>
       </React.Fragment>
     );
};
`

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to change the patern code?

*To something like this*

```
<ScrollView >
        <View> 
          <View>
          <Text>title</Text>
          <Image ..... />
          <Text/> 
           
        </View> 
      </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside "TextImg" you are giving both the 'Image' and 'Text' the `styles.propImg`.
This gives both of them height of 200px.

maybe try to change your "TextImg" like this:

```
export default function TextImg(props) {     
  return (        
    <React.Fragment>           
      <Text style = {props.style[0]}>{props.text} </Text>           
      <Image source={{uri: props.imageUri}}  style={props.style[1]}/>        
    </React.Fragment>      
  ); 
};
```

It should solve this issue.